# Deleting unknown level of array dynamic(not using eval)

Tags: php, arrays

I will have a lot unknown levels of array; I would like to delete the selected ones.

Example:

```
$data = array(
  'level1' => array(
      'level2' => array(
          'level3' => array(
             'level4' => 'the end level at currently example, but not always',
             'level4_remain' => 'this data will remain'
          ),
          'remain' => 'this data would not delete in this example too'
      )
   )
   'root' => 'this data would not delete in this example'
);
```

I have a class called vars; it stores all variables globally that I can fetch at anytime; add at anytime, but now that I'm going to make the delete method, I worry about the multi-level issue:

```
class vars {
   public static $data = array();

   public static function get($key){
      $key = explode('/', $key);
      $v = self::$data;

      foreach($key as $k)
      {

          if(!isset($v[$k]))
          {
              return null;
          }

          $v = &$v[$k];
      }

      return $v;
   }

   public static function has($key){
       .........
   }

   public static function del($key){
       $key = explode('/', $key);
       //....Any idea how to do this....//
   }
}
```

and I will use the `get` method like this:

```
$blabla = vars::get('level1/level2/level3/level4');
```

and return correct data, but in the `del method`, I have no idea what to do:

```
$deleted = vars::del('level1/level2/level3/level4');
```

It needs to be finished after deleting the array:

```
unset($data['level1']['level2']['level3']['level4']);
```

After doing some research I found this, but this is just for "set" level of array, not automatically set as many level as it can be:

```
foreach ($data as $k1 => $arr) {
    foreach ($arr as $k2 => $arr2) {
        foreach ($arr2 as $k3 => $arr3) {
            if ($k3 == $key) {
                unset($rules[$k1][$k2][$k3]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and I think it can be done like this but is quite ugly:

```
foreach($data as $k1 => $arr1){
   if(is_array($arr1)){
      foreach($arr1 as $k2 => $arr2){
          //...keep writing the if(is_array()){}else{} and foreach(){} for more level deeper...//
      }
   }else{
      //...the unset should be here...//
   }
}
```

After some research, `eval` might be harmful, so anyone have any ideas how to do this using any method except `eval`?

Comment: Why is eval harmful? Is harmful if misused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid `eval`, you can go the recursive route. The trick is to loop over your indices and pass a subarray reference repeatedly, similar to your get function, just recursively.

```
public static function del($key){
   $key = array_reverse( explode('/', $key) ); // _reverse for _pop later
   del_r(self::$data,$key); // start the recursive function
}

private static function del_r(&$array,$keys) { // shouldn't be used from outside
    $key = array_pop($keys); // extract next key, this removes it from $keys
    if (count($keys)) { // still keys left -> recurse further
        del_r($array[$key],$keys); // pass subarray by reference
    }
    else { // no more keys -> delete the element at the current $key
        unset($array[$key]);
    }
}
```

Depending on the number of keys, you can use `array_shift()` instead of `array_pop()` and remove the `array_reverse()`.

Comment: Actually I'm not sure if i got my referencing right... If it's wrong, I'd be happy to have it pointed out :)

Comment: erm, i have test this,but it delete whole OLD data container

so now my vars::get(); echo null // This should output everything but not the deleted key in array

Comment: Hm, then something's wrong with my referencing... Let me check that.

Comment: @user3040842 I completely changed my answer. I think recursion is the best approach.

Answer (score 1):

**If you don't mind using eval...**

```
public static function del($levels)
{
    $lvls = explode('/', $levels);
    $count = count($lvls);
    $eval = '';

    for ($i=0; $i<$count; ++$i) {
        // Current Array Key
        $key = $lvls[$i];
        $eval .= "['$key']"; 
    }
    $eval = 'self::data' . $eval;
    eval("unset($eval);");
}
```

However, running untrusted (like User input) through eval can be dangerous.

Comment: i think is ok, this class will not using any user input.thanks

Comment: @user3040842 `eval()` is not only bad due to its security risks, but also because it slows down execution (a little bit).

Comment: @ComFreek Well, compared with the accepted answer that rewrites the array, this is actually faster

Comment: @Tivie Have you made a benchmark? I would be curious to see it.